# Weird Error in Logcat with Socket.io Android client

Tags: android, socket.io-java-client

I have been using (and struggling with) Socket.io native Android client for a little while now and recently as I moved all my code from a Socket.io connexion stored in a static variable in `MyApplication extends Application` to a `SocketService extends Service`, in some situations my emits are just not heard by the server and I have this weird message in Logcat :

```
E/Socket.IO: [Ljava.lang.Object;@23ba63b6
```

(with @23ba.... being different everytime)

Anyone here ever seen a message like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Socket.io, but as a general rule of thumb: Unless you debug into their library code its unclear what the actual issue is. The error log seems to reference arguments of a method call, but that's all about it already that I can read out.

Try to dig deeper by debugging into their library (Android Studio / IntelliJ has code decompiler plugins that might help you even when stepping through obfuscated code) and if nothing helps, create a bug upstream and tell them that they should improve their error logging :)

Comment: I am kinda new to Java actually but do you think if I include the library code instead of importing it via Gradle, I could get more explicit error messages ? Like ideally a stacktrace ?

Comment: No, you won't. Gradle just stores your library dependency at a central place outside of your source root, otherwise the code is exactly the same.

Comment: Yes I tried actually. So do you think there's any way to get more info on this error knowing that it is is most likely caused by my own code.